# Catch "The In-App Purchase has already been bought" event

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
for (SKPaymentTransaction* transaction in transactions)
{
    CCLOG("transactionState = %ld", transaction.transactionState);
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The code above is for tracking the purchase state we know.
But it seems that the code won't track the event of "The In-App Purchase has already been bought".

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Each time I use the code above to purchase an IAP which is already purchased, the IOS confirm purchasing dialog will show out with transactionState = SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing(The output is "transactionState = 0"). Then I buy the item and "The In-App Purchase has already been bought" dialog show out with no other state code output.

I wish to catch the event above. I bet it must be catchable. Does the event is threw in other place?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I am running into a similar problem when calling addPayment for an already purchased item returns no callback event

Comment: No, after a long time solution finding end up with no result. I add some lock in my app to avoid the situation.

Comment: What kind of lock did you add?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by adding the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` to the `SKPaymentQueue` after another library had already registered its own observer.  Switching the order of initialization so that my app registered its own observer first fixed the problem.

[I've provided in more detail here](http://greensopinion.com/2017/03/22/This-In-App-Purchase-Has-Already-Been-Bought.html)

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar Issue when our server receipt validation stopped working and the transactions weren't finished. So I've modified the purchase flow. Before the App adds a new product payment the app iterates now through all open transactions (`[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions`) and stops the payment when an open transaction has the same product identifier as the new product payment.